# Getting Error while fetching text from screen - Error LookUpError : Unknown Encoding in Robot Framework

Tags: python, encoding, robotframework, lookup

I need to get the text from the screen and print Log to Console and store the same text in File but I am getting:

```
 Error as LookUpError : Unknown Encoding ;
```

( The text from the screen contains both ascii and special characters eg - Error = +. Error ++..  )

I have tried encoding the text as soon as I get it from the screen via the keyword "Encode to Bytes" but nothing worked .

```
${var} get text xpath="Some xpath value of the tag "

Log to console ${var}
```

Expected Result :

I want to print the value that I am getting from the screen and store it in a file

Actual Result :

I am getting the error while fetching value from screen - saying LookUpError : Unknown Encoding

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like:

```
Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath=//<some_xpath>
${text}=    Get Text    xpath=//<some_xpath>
Log    ${text}
```